# Cursor goes one character back in vim when changing modes

Tags: vim, cursor-position

When we go from `INSERT` mode to `NORMAL/COMMAND` mode by pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, the cursor shifts one position back.

I don't want this to happen. I want the cursor to be where it is even after I change into `COMMAND` mode.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295410/prevent-cursor-from-moving-back-one-character-on-insert-mode-exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior comes from good ol' vi. To change it:

```
:inoremap <Esc> <Esc>g`^
```

Comment: What does the `g` indicate here?

Comment: `g'` is like `'`, but doesn't add the jump to the jump list.