# Why does pressing escape go back one character?

Tags: vim

In vim, I've always been curious why pressing the <kbd>esc</kbd> key causes the cursor to go back by one character (usually). For example if I've typed:

```
This is |
```

With the cursor being the `|`, after I have finished typing and press <kbd>esc</kbd>, the line will look like:

```
This is|
```

And to re-type from where I left off I would have to press `a` instead of `i`. Why is this the expected behavior in vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following answer in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11405) on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange:

> In insert mode, the cursor is between characters, or before the first
>   or after the last character. In normal mode, the cursor is over a
>   character (newlines are not characters for this purpose). This is
>   somewhat unusual: most editors always put the cursor between
>   characters, and have most commands act on the character *after* (not,
>   strictly speaking, *under*) the cursor. This is perhaps partly due to
>   the fact that before GUIs, text terminals always *showed* the cursor
>   on a character (underline or block, perhaps blinking). This
>   abstraction fails in insert mode because that requires one more
>   position (posts vs fences).
>
> Switching between modes has to move the cursor by a half-character, so
>   to speak. The `i` command moves left, to put the cursor before the
>   character it was over. The `a` command moves right. Going out of
>   insert mode (by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>) moves the cursor left if
>   possible (if it's at the beginning of the line, it's moved right
>   instead).
>
> I suppose the <kbd>Esc</kbd> behavior sort of makes sense. Often,
>   you're typing at the end of the line, and there <kbd>Esc</kbd> can
>   only go left. So the general behavior is the most common behavior.
>
> Think of the character under the cursor as the last interesting
>   character, and of the insert command as `a`. You can repeat
>   <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> without moving the cursor, except that
>   you'll be bumped one position right if you start at the beginning of a
>   non-empty line.

Credits to  the original author.

If you would like to edit this behavior, you could follow the advice from @ib. in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2296229/3319589):

> Although I would not recommend changing the default cursor mechanics,
>   one way of achieving the behavior in question is to use the following
>   Insert-mode mapping.
>
> :inoremap   `^
>
> Here the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is overloaded in Insert mode to
>   additionally run the `` `^ `` command which moves the cursor to the
>   position where it had been the last time Insert mode was left. Since
>   in this mapping it is executed immediately after leaving Insert mode
>   with <kbd>Esc</kbd>, the cursor is left one character to the right as
>   compared to its position with default behavior.
>
> Unlike some other workarounds, this one does not require Vim to be
>   compiled with the `+ex_extra` feature.